# Can I change the collection name when I .save in mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Can I change the name of the collection where I save the data ? I have a model  for Game, and in the end I save data like this:

```
const teamData = new Game({
        id: id,
        homeTeamName: hTeam,
        awayTeamName: aTeam,
        homeTeamGoals: homeTeamGoals,
        awayTeamGoals: awayTeamGoals })

  teamData.save()
```

and every time it saves in collection Games, but can I use the same model for different collections. I have games from england, germany etc. Do I need model for every country or I can just give some collection name when I .save()

Comment: Why don't you just add a field for `country` to the Game model and set this field as England, Germany etc. You can even make a separate model for country and use relation field to this model.

Comment: Could you give me an example id I add a field for country ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here

1. add one more field `country` to your Model as

   ```
   const teamData = new Game({
   id: id,
   homeTeamName: hTeam,
   awayTeamName: aTeam,
   homeTeamGoals: homeTeamGoals,
   awayTeamGoals: awayTeamGoals,
   country: country})
   ```
2. Have a different collection called Countries where each document will have details related to that particular country and then store particular country's id in your Game Model.

Comment: Ok, but how to give country as a collection name ?

Comment: Why do you need to do that, Country will be a separate Collection so there will be a separate Model for this, and you will be mapping these two collections by putting  _id of country in Game(In case u are using Two different Collections) and In case you don't need a Separate Country Collection (if you don't have to store Country specific details) then just add one more field 'country' in Game Collection(and hence Model).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the documentation you can use the method [`model()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-model) passing a class extending Model instead of a string name.

*teamSchema* would be your generic schema

```
const teamSchema = new Schema({
    id: string,
    homeTeamName: string,
    awayTeamName: string,
    homeTeamGoals: number,
    awayTeamGoals: number
})
```

Then you can create a model each time you want to store a document in a different collection as:

```
const germanyModel = db.model('germany', new Game({
    id,
    homeTeamName: hTeam,
    awayTeamName: aTeam,
    homeTeamGoals,
    awayTeamGoals
}));

germanyModel.save()
```

If you want to do it programmatically, you could of course have a string variable that specifies the name of the collection:

```
const collection = 'spain';
const dynamicModel = db.model(collection, new Game({
    id,
    homeTeamName: hTeam,
    awayTeamName: aTeam,
    homeTeamGoals,
    awayTeamGoals
}));

dynamicModel.save()
```